# Split Array with looping on Python 2.7.5.1

Tags: python-2.7

```
def split(self):
    assert input_array >= 0
       if input_array == 0:
            return [0]
       array=[]
            while input_array> 0:
                array.append(int(input_array%10))
                input_array = input_array//10
                print input_array
            return input_array
        else:
            print "END"
```

is there any way to split input array with looping? 
i tried using selection but it just doesn't work

Comment: What is that? I'm not sure that sample code makes any sense. What do you actually want to do? input_array in your sample code isn't an array (list, in python terms) at all, it seems to be a number.

Comment: Maybe post a sample of the code which just has a sample array you are trying to split and then an idea of what you'd like the split result to look like. Normally if you wanted to split a list (array) in python you would use slicing (eg `input_array[:10]` <- first 10 items from the input_array)

Comment: _"i tried using selection but it just doesn't work"_. What is "selection"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the individual digits from a number? Try converting it into a string, iterating over it, and converting back to int.

```
>>> x = 2342
>>> [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]
[2, 3, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you want is a list of digits conforming a certain number (input_array in this case).

### First the main issues.

1. You declare a variable called `array` and if you are a good observer
   you will notice you never return it.
2. `print "END"` has no purpose here.
3. `input_arry == 0` can be treated as any other number > 0.
4. Try to not modify `input_array`

### The solution:

Since I see you're working with a class I will code a solution for you using a class as well.

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, input_array):
        """ Constructor """
        self.input_array = input_array

    def split(self):
        array = []
        number = self.input_array  # Don't modify input_array.
        while number > 0:
            array.append(number%10)
            number = number // 10
        array.reverse()             # This is easy ;)
        return array

    def split_1(self):
        """ Kevin's solution. When you become more skilled this is the way to go. """
        return [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]


>>> some_instance = SomeClass(12345)
>>> print(some_instance.split())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```